# Meaning of "play something out" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

I've come across it in the 11th episode of the 6th season of *the Walking Dead*. The context is a guy leads Rick and his friends to his camp. But, on the road they see a car crashed, which makes Rick suspicious of the guy's intentions.

> Rick: If it's a trick, it won't end well for you.
>
> The guy: My people are in trouble. They are... We don't have a lot of fighters. I know how it looks, but I'll **play it out**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sense is this one:

[Collins Dictionary "play out"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/play-out)

> 1. (transitive)
>    to finish
>    *let's play the game out if we aren't too late*

or

> 1. to play to the finish

It means that the guy will continue leading Rick, despite Rick's threat.